# How to check user permission in ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am want to check permission of the user in my ModelViewSet to understand how much data must be given to him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `self.request.user` like below

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySimpleSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return MyFullSerializer
        return super(MyViewSet, self).get_serializer_class()
```